# 301 redirect for many urls on nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect many old urls to newer ones on a nginx server.

If I google for a solution I mostly find complicated ways which are not very handy if I wnat redirect more than 100 urls.

Is there a solution to do this in a single line per redirect url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it was easy as hell :)

```
rewrite ^/old-url.php$ http://www.new-url.com/new-url.php permanent;
```